# How to preserve emojis when reading a csv file into pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding, emoji

I have a csv file with a column `message` which contains text (mainly in English but also with some special characters like Spanish or French) and emojis.

`df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding='utf-8')` gives me this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 83: invalid start byte`

`df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding='mac_roman')` reads the file ok but replaces emojis with underscore `_________`. The same with `windows-1252` and `iso-8859-1`.

I tried utf-16,32,cp1252 etc. Nothing works.

My aim is to keep emojis as there are and then decode them into words (smiley face, thumb up etc.) with the emoji python package.

Maybe someone had a similar problem and could suggest a way around? Thank you!

Comment: You do not have a UTF-8 encoding. Try to open the file with an other editor, and check which encoding you have. We cannot guess the encoding.

Comment: The encoding IS utf-8 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='myfile.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are telling pandas to read the files as if it was encoded as UTF-8, but the file is not an UTF-8. This is the meaning of the error. The strange thing: emojis practically exists only on Unicode formats (and some SMS encoding). Try to put also some text, and you will probably find some more data. UTF-16 and UTF-32 are not real encoding (if there is no BOM). Try the LE and BE variants.